# Using abbreviated code to specify a custom renderer using table1 in R

Tags: r

Hello I don't have many experience with R but I need help using abbreviated code to specify a custom renderer for the "table1" package in R. I would like to not display the default stats(FREQ,PCT) variable for categorical data and only display the frequency and omit the percent. The code in R Documentations show how to customize this for continuous variables and show some custom statistics for different variables.

This is just for the convenience of displaying a frequency table with the built html formatting of package 1. I do know how to get this information otherwise. I am interested learning how to use more this package in R.

```
rndr <- function(x, name, ...)
  {(what <- switch(name,
        c_race = "FREQ",
    parse.abbrev.render.code(c("", what))(x))
}


table1::table1(~c_race|c_ethnicity*c_gender, data = childlearn_demo, 
   render=rndr, overall="Total",topclass="Rtable1-zebra")
```

Comment: I know I can get these results by using ftable but like mentioned before this is out convenience/stubbornness

Comment: Can you provide your data, or a sample of it? Or, the results of using ftable or table1 with the default output including PCT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of "abbreviated code" is to allow flexibility without needing to write your own function. Thus, you can get the desired result by simply using `render.categorical="Freq"`, i.e.:

```r
table1::table1(~ c_race|c_ethnicity*c_gender, data = childlearn_demo,
   overall="Total",topclass="Rtable1-zebra", render.categorical="Freq")
```

(note: I am the table1 package author)

Comment: Thank you!! Wow I am so thankful for table1. Thanks for creating the code and answering my question.

Comment: Thanks and you're welcome. If you are satisfied, please "accept" the answer by  clicking the checkmark near the post (on the left).